Polymorphism in Swift - Function override
There is a base class:
class Base {
    func foo<S: Base>(to value: S) {
        print("Base class foo")
    }
}

and a derived ones from Base:
class One: Base {
    func foo(to value: Two) {
        print("foo: Two")
    }
}

class Two: Base {
    func foo(to value: One) {
        print("foo: One")
    }
}

class Three: Base {
    func foo(to value: One) {
        print("foo: One")
    }
}

Example usage:
var sample: Base = One()

sample.foo(Two())    // expected "foo: Two"
sample.foo(Three())  // expected Base class implementation to be called "Base class foo"

The idea is to get called the "specialized" func variant from One, Two or Three in case the derived class's implementation exists or default to Base class implementation using generics. My attempt was to add the keyword override but the compiler reports the derived class's function does not override anything and only the base class func is called every single time...

You get the expected output if you declare sample as var sample: One = One(). And you can override foo but the override needs the same generic declaration.


My attempt was to add the keyword override but the compiler reports the derived class's function does not override anything and only the base class func is called every single time

Because you are not giving the same generic signature as the method in the base class. As @HangarRash mentioned if you do not put the same signature, compiler does not allow you to use override keyword. This is how it should look like:
class Base {
    func foo<S: Base>(to value: S) {
        print("Base class foo")
    }
}

class One: Base {
    override func foo<S: Base>(to value: S) {
        guard let value = value as? Two else {
            super.foo(to: value)
            return
        }
        print("foo: Two")
    }
}


This works but the problem is that you must remember to implement the guard statement in all subclasses that override the foo method.
